# undefined reference to a library function but same message doesn't appear in other computers

Tags: c++, qt, svn, linker, undefined-reference

I have written a `QT` application that consists of three projects: Lib, RT, Gui.

Lib has been created as shared library and it is used by RT and Gui.

I have create an svn repository where I commit all the changes. With my first computer there are no compilation nor linking problems.

When I check out from the svn in my second pc (where I have installed a different linux distribution), if I try to compile Lib and RT there are no problems but when compiling Gui I get 10 error messages of this type:

> /path_to_the_project_folder/lib/core.so:-1: error: undefined reference
>   to `mylibnamespace::Converter::Converter(int)'

It should mean that Converter::Converter(int)' is not defined but instead it is, in fact in the first pc it works.

I have been thinking that maybe it is due to the fact that in the svn there may be old object files but there aren't, and anyway, I do a clean project before compiling.

I have tried also to update the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file with the lib path and other stuff but it seems that everything is ok.

The .pro files seem ok as well since they work in the first pc.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: is there any preprocessor macro related to the Converter Class?

Comment: yes, there's some define but there are messages of another class that doesn't use defines

Comment: another strange thing is that, RT uses Lib but there, there aren't error messages!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution..

it was the order of the libs

LIBS += -myproj1 -myproj2 ...

instead of 
LIBS += -myproj2 -myproj1 ...

I don't know why in the other pc worked but this is the solution.